# illustrate a special function using scilab

Tags: plot, scilab

I have written a function to find `Log(Fn) / n`, where `Fn` is the sequence of Fibonacci numbers `F_{n+1} = F_n + F_{n-1}`:

```
function [g] = logf(n)
    u = 0;
    v = 1;
    f = v;
    for i = 2:n do
        f = u + v;
        u = v;
        v = f;
    end
    g = log(f) / n;
endfunction
```

What I need is to plot this function for `1< n < 200`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First all please try to learn MarkDown language to post readable questions. Your first question had some information which was not shown due to the conflicts with StackOverflow's MarkDown rendering.

Secondly try to modularize your code as much as possible and use the convention I have used to have a more readable code. Define a Fibonacci using a for loop:

```
function y = fibonacci(N)
    select N
    case 0 then
        y = 0;
    case 1 then
        y = 1;
    else
        y0 = 0;
        y1 = 1;
        y = 1;
        for ii = 3:N do
            y0 = y1;
            y1 = y
            y = y1 + y0;
        end
    end
endfunction
```

Then you have two options:

**A.** define your function in a vectorized form:

```
function [g] = logf(n)
    for ii = n do
        g(ii) = log(fibonacci(ii)) / ii;
    end
endfunction
```

consider that Scilab does not broadcast matrices / lists over functions and you should do that your self.

Now you can plot with:

```
n = 1:200; 
plot(n, logf(n));
```

And the result is:

> [image]

**B.** Alternatively you could map or broadcast your function over the sequence using `feval`. Define your function in scalar form:

```
function [g] = logf(n)
    g = log(fibonacci(n)) / n;
endfunction
```

and then plot with:

```
n = 1:200; 
plot(n, feval(n, logf));
```

Comment: happy to see it helped you. do not forget to accept the correct solutions and give them thumbs up.