# finding intersection point using scilab

Tags: scilab

How can I find intersection points in the graph shown below using `fsolve` function *(from `scilab`)*?

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
function y=f(x)
    y = 30 + 0 * x;
endfunction


function y= g(x)
    y=zeros(x)
    k1 = find(x >= 5 & x <= 11); 
    if  k1<>[]  then
        y(k1)= -59.535905 +24.763399*x(k1) -3.135727*x(k1)^2+0.1288967*x(k1)^3;
    end;
    k2=find(x >= 11 & x <= 12); 
    if  k2 <> []    then 
        y(k2)=1023.4465 - 270.59543 * x(k2) + 23.715076 * x(k2)^2 - 0.684764 * x(k2)^3; 
    end;
    k3 = find(x >= 12 & x <= 17);    
    if  k3 <> [] then
        y(k3) =-307.31448 + 62.094807 *x(k3) - 4.0091108 * x(k3)^2 + 0.0853523 * x(k3)^3;
    end;
    k4 = find(x >= 17 & x <= 50); 
    if k4 <> [] then 
        y(k4) = 161.42601 - 20.624104 *x(k4) + 0.8567075 * x(k4)^2 - 0.0100559 * x(k4)^3;
    end;
endfunction

t=[5:50];
plot(t, g(t));
plot2d(t, f(t));
deff('res = fct', ['res(1) = f(x)'; 'res(2) = g(x)']);
k1=[5, 45];
xsol1 = fsolve(k1, f, g)
```

> [image]

Comment: y=30+0*x has no intersection

Comment: Did you look at the help file https://help.scilab.org/doc/6.0.0/en_US/fsolve.html? Your jacobian g has nothing to do with your function f. And I'm wondering if you even tried to run your code, which looks quite ok except for the extra text in []...

Comment: when you do not spend time to format your question properly, you are actually telling your peers that I do not care about this issue at all, leading not receiving proper answers. please learn MarkDown to be able to post proper posts here on stackoverflow. Apart from that your first "equation" is basically a constant. Why you are defining a function at all?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original post was utterly unreadable and chaotic. It took me while to edit it and understand what you are trying to achieve. However I will try to help you. Lets go step by step:

1. I am not sure why you have used `find` function this way. probably you were trying to vectorize the `g` function? Please consider that Scilab does not broadcast functions over arrays by default. You need to either vectorize them or use `feval` to do so. Please read [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55202041/4999991) I have written before.  `find` is a vectorized operation applying on an array, a Boolean operation and a scalar, finding the elements of the array which satisfy the operation. For example from [the `find` page](https://help.scilab.org/doc/5.3.3/en_US/find.html):

```
beers = ["Desperados", "Leffe", "Kronenbourg", "Heineken"];
find(beers == "Leffe")
```

returns `2` and

```
A = rand(1, 20);
w = find(A < 0.4)
```

returns those elements of array `A` which are smaller than `0.4`.

2. Please learn about conditionals and specifically `if, then, elsif, else, end` statements. If you learn this you will not use the `find` function in that way. Sometimes you have so many `if`s in a row, then try to use `select, case, else, end` instead. Your second function could be written as:

```
function y = g(x)
  if x < 5 | 50 < x then
    error("Out of range");
  elseif x <= 11 then
    y = -59.535905 + 24.763399 * x - 3.135727 * x^2 + 0.1288967 * x^3;
    return;
  elseif x <= 12 then
    y = 1023.4465 - 270.59543 * x + 23.715076 * x^2 - 0.684764 * x^3;
    return;
  elseif x <= 17 then
    y = -307.31448 + 62.094807 * x - 4.0091108 * x^2 + 0.0853523 * x^3;
    return;
  else
    y = 161.42601 - 20.624104 * x + 0.8567075 * x^2 - 0.0100559 * x^3;
  end
endfunction
```

3. Now apparently you want to find the points on this curve which have a value of `30`. Although there are methods to find these points automatically plotting can be very helpful to find the proper range:

```
t = [5:50];
plot(t, feval(t, g) - 30)
```

> [image]

showing that the the two solutions are in the range of `20 < x1 < 30` and `40 < x < 50`.

4. Now if we use `fsolve` with the proper initial values it gives us good results:

```
--> deff('[y] = g2(x)', 'y = g(x) - 30');

--> fsolve([25; 45], g2)
 ans  =

   26.67373
   48.396547
```

5. The third parameter of the `fsolve` function is the Jacobin / derivative of the `g(x)` function. You either should calculate the derivatives of the above polynomials manually (or use a proper symbolic software like Maxima), or define them as polynomials using `poly` function. See [this tutorial](https://x-engineer.org/graduate-engineering/programming-languages/scilab/define-solve-polynomials-scilab/) for example. Then  differentiate them, defining a new function like `dgdx`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190537/discussion-on-answer-by-foad-finding-intersection-point-using-scilab).

Comment: @Foad hey mr foad, how are you? I hope you're fine, I asked you how to do for a vertical line and points of intersection, the following equation g (x) = x is correct and then we use fsolve such as' g (x) -30 'skylines?
if i initialize fsolve on the whole interval [0:50] is it ok?

Comment: Dear @CodyGray I do not appreciate my comments being moved to chat without discussing it first with the people involved. I don't like to use chats because they are not indexed by search engines leading to many useful information being lost.

Comment: Moderators don't discuss moving comments to chat. It happens when the comment thread goes on and on, back and forth between two users. Your point about information getting lost because it is not indexed by search engines is valid. That's why you should [edit] the answer to include any necessary information. Search engines don't do a good job of indexing comments, either, that's why they're treated as temporary. A long chain of back-and-forth comments are difficult to follow, and will mostly be unread.