# How to compute area in scilab and find points of intersections by an algorithm

Tags: scilab, integral

This code represents the plot of the function g with two horizontal lines and one vertical line:

```
function y = g(x)
    if x < 5 | 50 < x then
        error("Out of range");
    elseif x <= 11 then
        y = -59.535905 + 24.763399 * x - 3.135727 * x^2 + 0.1288967 * x^3;
        return;
    elseif x <= 12 then
        y = 1023.4465 - 270.59543 * x + 23.715076 * x^2 - 0.684764 * x^3;
        return;
    elseif x <= 17 then
        y = -307.31448 + 62.094807 *x - 4.0091108 * x^2 + 0.0853523 * x^3;
        return;
    else
        y = 161.42601 - 20.624104 * x + 0.8567075 * x^2 - 0.0100559 * x^3;
    end
endfunction 

**//this represents the vertical line**    
a=linspace(45,45,60)
b=linspace(0,70,60)
plot(a,b,style='r')

**//this represents the first horizontal line**    
a=linspace(0,60,60)
b=linspace(30,30,60)
plot(a,b,style='g')

//this represents the second horizontal line    
a=linspace(0,60,60)
b=linspace(40,40,60)
plot(a,b,style='g')

//this is the graph of function "g"
t = [5:50];
plot(t, feval(t, g));

// the  part of code  is for to find the solution of fsolve
//plot(t, feval(t, g)-30);
//plot(t, feval(t, g)-60);

//deff('[y] = g2(x)', 'y = g(x)-30');
//deff('[y] = g3(x)', 'y = g(x)-40');
```

The problem is that I want to find the four points of intersection between the curve and the three lines and calculate the colored surface. and how can I colorful this area in Scilab because I used paint to better explain the figure. and welcome any help.

> [image]

Comment: Sad to see that you did not take a look at the edits I applied to your former post. :(

Comment: @Foad  Oh no my dear friend, I told you that I posted the problem so that the code and the figure are very clear, that's all, so your help is precious and I do not know how to do it to thank you

Comment: I see that Stephanie has already answered your question. he is way way more competent. his answer is very concise.

Answer (score 1):

you just have to integrate `max(0,min(g(x),40)-30)` between x=45 and x=50.

```
integrate('max(0,min(g(x),40)-30)','x',45,50)
```

Before testing please change the first test of your `g` function to `if 50 < x then` (there is currently a bug in `integrate`, which calls the function to integrate with 1 as argument regardless of integration domain)

Comment: previous discussions about this post [here the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55230860/4999991).

Comment: Dear Stéphane, [these](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/scilab) are the most viewed / voted unanswered question about Scilab. it would be great if you could also take a look at them

Comment: Many of these are very old and my experience is that the authors of such questions just passed away... Some of them already have answers which are correct and have never been accepted as such.

Comment: true, but their view counts shows that they are still relevant. many people who end up there through search engines could be helped imo.

Comment: @Stéphane Mottelet, bonjour mr Stéphane , j'ai pas compris ce que vous voulez dire par il y a bug  pour le test de x<50